# Search page using Sweetalert

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, post

I'm trying to create a page named 'list of users' where I have a sweetalert with input text form and user enters a name in sweetalert and then using a POST method like a form to redirect to mywebsite.com/search and show results with that name.
Sweetalert is putted on homepage.

```
<script>
    function searchp()
{
    Swal({
        title: 'Search',
        input: 'text',
        inputPlaceholder: 'enter_name',
        inputAttributes: {
          autocapitalize: 'off'
        },
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: 'Search',
        confirmButtonColor: '#ffffff',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33'
    }).then(result => {
        if (result.value) {
            $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: '<?php echo base_url("search"); ?>',
                  data: {
                       //here 1
                  },
                  success: function(data)
                  {
                    //here 2
                  }
            });
          } else {
            Swal(
                'Ops!',
                'You canceled.',
                'error'
            )
          }
    })
}
</script>
```

As you saw I don't know how to apply POST method on ''. I'm using Codeigniter 3 as php framework.
 is equal to mywebsite.com/search.

I want after a user entered name in input form and pressed submit to apply post method on search page and show results there. The backend for search page is already made and is working with a normal  tag.

Answer (score 0):

Hey if you want to redirect the page then you don't need ajax request at all. First get the input value and then use it as a parameter in your wanted URL. I've created a demo, see if this works for you. ↓↓

```js
function searchp() {
  Swal.fire({
    title: 'Search',
    input: 'text',
    inputPlaceholder: 'Enter Name',
    inputAttributes: {
      autocapitalize: 'off'
    },
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: 'Search',
    //confirmButtonColor: '#eee',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    preConfirm: (data) => {
      if (data != "") {
        // window.location = '<?php echo base_url('search')?>' + data;
        // or(whichever works for you)
        // window.location = '<?php echo base_url('search')?>' + '/' + data;
        console.log(`Your name: ${data}`)
      } else {
        Swal.showValidationMessage(`Please enter name`)
      }
    },
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9.10.12/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="searchp()" >Fire Sweet Alert</button>
```